# Handle multiple database connections in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I'm currently trying to figure out what would be the best way to handle a lot of database-connections.

First of all a basic outline of the project I need to realize:

We have a bunch of xml-files with instructions for the application. In the application they are represented as objects. These objects are placed in a queue and which will be processed in one of four threads.

Each of these xml-file objects will generate an export to an individual mysql-database and a big status-database.

My problem is, that I'm unsure how to handle these mysql-database connections best. The first hunch I had was to open the status-database once and pass it as an object to each of the xml-file objects. However the application will run for a long time so I'd definitely run in an connection error.

The other way would be to open a connection in each xml-objects once the data-export is ready, which seems not really performant to me.

How should I handle this connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shall not use separate sessions/connections for each "export task". Each login to database will cause non-necessary operations (like writes to database log) and this will slow down your entire application.

If you are expecting connection problems - use try-catch and handle database exceptions and just reconnect when connection broken.

Comment: That's exactly what I feared would happen. So the best course of action would be to have a class for the database connection and in there handle the reconnect with the try-catch?

Comment: Yes. Especially in application that works continuously. Also some query queue would be nice in that database class.

Comment: That's brilliant! It would never occurred to me to also use a query queue! Thank you very much for your help and insight!